# Xcode version preprocessor

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I have a small bug in my application that only exists when building with Xcode 6. I fixed this bug, but then this part is bugged when building with Xcode 5.
So there is an ugly battle between the two Xcode versions..

Now.. I want to check which Xcode version is being used to build the project via a preprocessor. Is this possible to do so? If so, this would fix my problem really fast.

Comment: I'd think that it should be possible using [preprocessor macros](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) to get the compiler version used by XCode: *"The version of Clang distributed with Apple XCode 4.4 is branded as "Apple Clang 4.0" and derives from the open source Clang 3.1 distribution, but defines these macros with the values `4` and `0` respectively. Apple's Clang distribution can be identified by the presence of the `__apple_build_version__` macro."*

Comment: Hi! How do I check this? I'm a bit stuck on this :o

Comment: It's unlikely that you have a bug caused by the version of Xcode. Post (in your question) the relevant code giving you the issue and explain what problem you have between the two versions. It's probably a difference in the Base SDK used between the two versions.