# "if (@available(iOS 13.0, *))" doesn't compile in Xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, preprocessor-directive

I have such code:

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    if([getMetalDevice() supportsFamily:MTLGPUFamilyApple3])
        pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA10_XR;
    else
        pixelFormat =  MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
}
```

It works in Xcode 11, but doesn't work in Xcode 10.3. 
A preprocessor says it doesn't know what is `MTLGPUFamilyApple3` (which was introduced in iOS 13).

I tried to use a preprocessor macro:

```
#define isIOS13 (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_13_0)
```

but a preprocessor complains `Function-like macro 'floor' is not defined`.

The same for

```
#define isIOS13 (int(NSFoundationVersionNumber) >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_13_0)
```

I need to use both Xcode 10.3 ( iOS 12.4 ) and Xcode 11 ( iOS 13.0 ) because of stability reasons.

What can I do to make my code work in both Xcodes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765740/xcode-version-preprocessor

Comment: @Almo I've seen `__apple_build_version__` in the link you provided, but there're no examples how to use it

Comment: Application build with Xcode 10.3 will not support `MTLGPUFamilyApple3` anyway. Are you sure you need support project compilation on both Xcodes?

Comment: @Cy-4AH `Xcode 10.3 will not support MTLGPUFamilyApple3` - yes, but it will compile the code with `#ifdef Xcode11`.  Part of my team works in Xcode11, another part works with Appium for automated tests, Appium's support for real devices isn't good yet for Xcode 11.

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk, Appium's support for real devices isn't good for applications build with Xcode 11 or with installed iOS version 13?

Comment: @Cy-4AH It seems with Xcode 11, because the device's iOS version is 12.4.1 :)

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk in that case I think problem is in builded with Xcode 11 binary. For example I have seen broken UI, but if I build with Xcode 10.1 all if fine. I think you are going to distribute binary builded with Xcode 11 and tests performed with binary builded with 10.3 can't be trusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_13_0
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    if([getMetalDevice() supportsFamily:MTLGPUFamilyApple3])
        pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA10_XR;
    else
#else
{
#endif
        pixelFormat =  MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
}
```

But you should use this code only if you provide some opensource library that support several Xcodes.

If this is part of yours project, you should just migrate to new Xcode and
doesn't overcomplicate yours code with preprocessor operators.

Better to solve problems with Appium instead of this.