# Xcode is throwing compile error even if use #available for older version Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Xcode14 is throwing compile error -

[image]

When I use clipsToBounds property in Mac OS 14 with Xcode 15 it works.
I need to run code on both Xcode 15 and Xcode 14.

I added availability check, but its failing at compile time.

any suggestion?

Comment: Also this seems to be Objective-C code, so please don't tag [swift], and post your code as *text*, not an image.

Comment: I am talking about 'NSView' only. if it's available from macOS 10.9, then why it is throwing error on Xcode 14.3.1 and working on Xcode 15.  if I put macOS 10.9 availability  in code its throwing same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["if (@available(iOS 13.0, \*))" doesn't compile in Xcode 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083310/if-availableios-13-0-doesnt-compile-in-xcode-10-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to support both Xcode 14 and Xcode 15 while also wanting to take advantage of new APIs added in macOS 14.0, you need to make use of the `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` macro.

In your specific case you would want:

```objc
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 140000 // Only true in Xcode 15.0+
    myNSView.clipsToBounds = YES;
#endif
```

`clipsToBounds` is a weird case since it became public in Xcode 15 but it can now be used with a deployment target back to macOS 10.9.

The more general approach, when needing to support an API added in macOS 14.0 and not available at all prior to that, and your app has a deployment target older than macOS 14.0, all while supporting Xcode 14 and 15, then you need something like the following:

```objc
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 140000
    // Built with Xcode 15.0+
    if (@available(macOS 14.0, *)) {
        someObject.someNewProperty = someValue;
    } else {
        // optional code for pre-macOS 14.0
        someObject.someOldProperty = someValue;
    }
#else
    // Built with Xcode before 15.0
    // optional code for pre-macOS 14.0
    someObject.someOldProperty = someValue;
#endif
```

Once you stop trying to support Xcode 14 you can remove everything between `#else` and `#endif, and remove the` #if`,` #else`, and` #endif` lines.

The downside to this is that if you do have alternate code for older versions of macOS while supporting multiple versions of Xcode, that code gets repeated in two places.

The following resolves the duplicate code issue:

```objc
    if (@available(macOS 14.0, *)) {
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 140000
        // Built with Xcode 15.0+
        someObject.someNewProperty = someValue;
#endif
    } else {
        // optional code for pre-macOS 14.0
        someObject.someOldProperty = someValue;
    }
```

Once you stop trying to support Xcode 14 you can remove the `#if` and `#endif` lines.

---

Note: There is a macro named `__MAC_14_0` that is defined as `140000` and using it would make the code easier to read. But that macro would only be defined when using Xcode 15 and not when using Xcode 14.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `clipsToBounds` ships with macOS 14 SDK, which includes Xcode 15. In Xcode below 15, this property is not available, so the compiler cannot find it and throws an error. It's just a kind of syntax detection.

The release note is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-14#NSView).

> In macOS 14, AppKit is exposing the clipsToBounds property of NSView.

**Updated:** You can use preprocessors which define in `<AvailabilityMacros.h>` to cover this case

```objectivec
//You don't really need to import this
//#import <AvailabilityMacros.h>
...

//You can also check all available versions in the AvailabilityVersions.h file.
//140000 means MacOS 14.0
#if __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 140000
    view.clipsToBounds = YES;
#endif
```

Comment: if I add below code still it throws error -

 if (@available(macOS 14.0, *)) {
    myNSView.clipsToBounds = YES;
  }

Comment: Absolutely yes on Xcode below 15, what do you expect? Are you confused `@available` and `#if`? It isn't relevant to the @available macro here.

Comment: with #if, how we can check for Mac OS version availability ?

Comment: I updated the answer, you may want to take a look.

Comment: FYI - you don't need to explicitly import AvailabilityMacros.h. You usually get it automatically through other main imports you would use in an AppKit app (or other frameworks). It's also best to avoid using numbers such as `140000`. There are much more human readable macros (as seen in my answer).

Comment: Thanks @HangarRash, I updated it, and my purpose is to point out to OP that there are preprocessors in AvailabilityMacros.h that can support in this scenario. Beside that, it seems like __MAC_14_0 doesn't really work on the lower Xcode version (I tried on 14.3.1), so I decided to use its value directly.

Comment: @son Good point about the `__MAC_14_0` macro. That probably isn't defined in Xcode 14. I don't actually have Xcode 14 so I didn't catch that oversight in my answer. I need to update for that.